# Processing Tag Suggested for General "processing" Questions

Tags: discussion, tags

I lurk on the [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) tag quite a bit, waiting for new questions about the [Processing](https://processing.org/) language, which is what the tag is meant for.

However, many of the questions tagged as processing are for things like image processing, processing data, etc. I assume StackOverflow is picking up on the word "processing" in their post and suggesting the processing tag. But what would a general "processing" tag even mean?

I usually edit these posts, or comment about removing the processing tag, and it usually gets done- but is there a way to avoid this step by not suggesting the processing tags for every post that contains the word "processing"? Is there a better way to handle improperly tagged posts?

PS- Yes, Processing is a terrible name for a language.

Comment: Pretty sure users are just adding that tag without explicit prompting.  Consider having a slightly different tag name to represent the language that makes it clearer that it's referring to a programming language (i.e. [tag:processing-language] or something like that), rather than a concept; it would help with mistagging.

Comment: @Servy Sounds good to me. Or maybe a prompt when somebody adds the processing tag, like, "Note: the processing tag is for the Processing language, not general data processing questions." I guess something like that already displays when you use a tag, but people seem to be ignoring it. A minor annoyance, but an annoyance nonetheless!

Comment: No need for that, we have the tools to clean up the tag.  Considering the name and the probable popularity of the language, I would suggest the creation and migration of questions to [processing-lang].