# Rename [processing] to [processing-language] or similar

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Would it be useful/accepted to rename the [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) tag to something that signifies that it is a standalone computer language?

Why:

Apparently [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) is a language. Since there is no special indication that particular tag is a "language" tag it is hard for non-initialed to understand that question with java-looking code is actually properly tagged with language tag already.

Additionally as covered in [[Processing Tag Suggested for General "processing" Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280023/processing-tag-suggested-for-general-processing-questions]) there are random questions that get tagged "processing", possibly due to presence of the word in a post.

Alternative suggestions:

- turn on Java syntax highlighting may be enough for random readers to notice that post is already marked with some sort of language and don't need any comments like "please add language tag".
- (as Processing is basically Java) to suggest/automatically tag with "java" too, but it may include questions about Processing IDEs as covered in [Should [processing] questions also be tagged with [java]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251014/should-processing-questions-also-be-tagged-with-java).

I personally would prefer "processing-lang", but it looks like "-language" suffix is by far more common for tags.

---

Note that there is relatively small number of questions (~2400) so not really problematic to stay the way it is now, but could minimize confusion for people scanning new questions for completeness.

Comment: Yes, it should be re-named. But a more mportant reason is not gathering all those questions where noobs ask about processing something, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686979/java-file-line-processing-basics

Answer (score 7):

This tag should be renamed to [processing-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing-lang) and have [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) created and synonymized to it as gnat and Bhargav originally suggested.

While this won't solve the issue of users using the tag when they are talking about processing data of some kind as Kevin Workman mentioned, it *will* solve the issue of users reviewing [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) questions and reacting as if the question does not have a language tag (as happened to me today).

In my opinion the Processing language and its syntax are not distinct enough from others to intuitively discern "this is a novel programming language"; to me it looks like it could be Java or some other popular language, and if the tags just include [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) and, say [random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/random), it can lead well-meaning users to ask unnecessarily about what language the user is using, or close the questions as needing details/an MCVE/MRE. Personally, I can't guarantee that I'll always remember that Processing is a language of its own, so this may even happen to me again in the future if the tag remains the same.

Answer (score 6):

I guess the question becomes: how do we indicate to real Processing users that they should stop using [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) and start using the new [processing-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing-language)? Would you completely eliminate the [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) tag in favor of its replacement?

Other alternatives might be [p5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p5) or the already-existent [processing.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing.org).

Another problem is that, well, Processing isn't really synonymous with Java anymore. [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) is becoming pretty huge: does that get its own tag? (Edit: it did: [processing.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing.js) Now what about [p5.js](http://p5js.org/)?)

This is one of my pet peeves on StackOverflow, so I hope it does get addressed, but I'm not sure what the solution is.

Comment: my understanding is, if [processing] becomes [tag-synonym](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-synonyms/info "what's this") of [processing-lang] this will smoothly achieve desired change. Per my recollection of how this feature works users won't even need to know about [processing-lang] but any time they will try to enter [processing] system will automagically change it to [processing-lang]

Comment: A rename of the tag (and then a synonym, like what @gnat mentions) would automatically migrate all the users, favorites, watches, etc to use the new tag . Would that be a good option here?

Comment: @BhargavRao Unfotunately, I doubt that renaming the tag will solve the problem. After several years of untagging non-Processing posts, I'd say that 90% of the problematic posts are first-time posters asking questions that are much too broad, usually about mathematica. I doubt these users will notice that the tag says processing-language, or know what it means.

Comment: @KevinWorkman My though is, if 50% of the users notice it, it'll reduce 50% of the work for you, which you can use to answer other questions instead. What percentage of users out of the 90%, do you think, would notice it? Another question, Would a rename to [processing.org-language] instead of [processing-language] be useful? (related story - there was an issue with the [tag:booking-api], where users were using the tag to post really useless questions. A rename to [tag:booking.com-api], has fixed most of the issues)

Comment: @BhargavRao Honestly it's not that much work for me. I've gotten pretty good at the "edit tags, remove processing, downvote, vote to close as too broad" muscle memory. I'd rather make it as easy as possible for legitimate Processing users to find the tag. I think keeping it as [tag:processing] is okay. I'd also be fine with renaming it to [tag:processing-language]. Something like [tag:processing.org-language] is probably not correct, since processing.org encompasses several other languages, e.g. [tag:p5.js]. In the end I don't think any solution is perfect, just because the name is so general.

Comment: Cool, if it isn't much work for you, then I'm fine with it remaining so. Thanks!