# Posts incorrectly tagged "processing": edit or comment?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) tag is supposed to be for questions about the Processing language, but the tag often gets inundated with "general processing" questions, which are pretty meaningless. I've mentioned the problem of "general processing" posts being tagged with the [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) tag [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280023/processing-tag-suggested-for-general-processing-questions), and renaming it has been discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286694/rename-processing-to-processing-language-or-similar).

My question is: should I leave a comment to the OP saying that "The [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language", or should I edit the post to remove the tag myself?

Originally I was editing the posts. But I didn't really see an "incentive" to doing that, plus that process takes me much longer than it does to simply paste in a comment.

So, I've been pasting in the comment instead, but then somebody told me that I should be editing the posts.

However, the help pages on [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) and [editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) both say:

> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.
>
> Editing a post also bumps the question to the top of the homepage. Please be mindful of this and make your edits count, so that the new attention is brought to something substantial.

That leads me to believe that editing out a tag should be avoided, especially because many of the questions with a "general processing" tag are of pretty low quality.

What's the best approach? Is there an incentive to taking the time to edit the post?

Comment: I sometimes see off-beam posts arriving in the tags I look at. I have no qualms about editing to remove the tag and also leaving a comment. I do fix anything else I can see in the post. However, if there were large numbers (I see perhaps one every two months) I'd probably still do the same, but with less enthusiasm.

Answer (score 0):

If you have editing privileges, there is no incentive other than badges. I know that trivial edits are discouraged, but **retagging is almost never a trivial edit**. If there is a post that has one or two minor grammar problems, it is still most likely understandable and editing it doesn't really help very much. However, a question that is incorrectly tagged is a bigger problem. Tags are used to sort questions; if I want to find Processing language questions, having to manually wade through many general-processing-related questions isn't a tiny annoyance, it's a fairly large problem.

In my opinion, the best thing to do is **both edit and comment**. That way, the OP knows not to use [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) for any general-processing-related question and the post doesn't dilute actual Processing questions.